# Find the vector given conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $\vec{x}_0 = (1,2)$ and consider the set $\{x ∈ \mathbb{R}^2\ :\ \|x\| + \|x − x_0\| = 1\}$.

What are possible vectors for $\vec{x}$?

This is what I've done so far and get stuck:
Yeah I know that, It's just that if $\vec{x}=\langle a,b\rangle$ such that $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, I get $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+ \sqrt{(a-1)^2+(b-2)^2} = 1$ which I can then move the second term (under the square root) to the right side of the equation and square everything. Then move things around and square again and then I get this very messy equation ==> $4ab-4a-8b+4+3b^2 = 0$, which I can't seem to make much sense of geometrically, even when I complete the square.

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{(a-1)^2+(b-2)^2} = 1$ is already in about as simple of a form as it can get, I think.  Maybe you'll recognize this as the equation of an ellipse with foci at $(0,0)$ and $(1,2)$ (and thus a center as $\left(\frac 12, 1\right)$).  Perhaps you're wanting to parametrize this ellipse?

Comment: I changed $\vec x$=<a,b> to $\vec x = \langle a,b\rangle$ and $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$+ $\sqrt{(a-1)^2+(b-2)^2} = 1$ to $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+ \sqrt{(a-1)^2+(b-2)^2} = 1$.  Both are standard usage.  Notice that in the expression with the radical the font used for $\text{“}+\text{''}$ does not match and lacks proper spacing when that is excluded from MathJax. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Bye_World, very good point -- thanks!